# Use specific SSH Key for a specific host in Eclipse like SSH Config in Linux?

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am using Eclipse since years (Ubuntu and Windows in parallel), and the projects are growing...

However, I am using many remote GIT repositories with SSH Keys that are protected by passphrases.

My problem is that Eclipse asks me for all passphrases every time I want to push to a server, which is very annoying. And I can't find a way to tell Eclipse which SSH Key belongs to which host.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you try `~/.ssh/config` and manual page for `ssh_config`?

Comment: Yes, I am using ssh_config, but my problem is not the SSH via console but in Eclipse.